# bash - "for i in *.mp4" how to not print "*.mp4" if it doesn't find any files?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm writing a script to print resolutions of my media files using MediaInfo. I hard coded the marvel directory in just for testing and getting the cuts right.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in /mnt/D/tv/"Marvel (MCU)"/{*.mp4,*.mkv,*.avi,*.m4v}; do 
    mediainfo "$i" > temp
    H=`cat temp | grep "Height" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -c 2- | cut -d "p" -f 1`
    W=`cat temp | grep "Width" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -c 2- | cut -d "p" -f 1`
    printf "%-50s %s x %s \n" "$(basename "$i")" "$W" "$H"
    rm temp
done
```

Output:

```
1. Iron Man.mp4                                    1 920  x 800  
10. Guardians of the Galaxy.mp4                    1 280  x 536  
... 
8. Thor The Dark World.mkv                         1 920  x 800  
9. Captain America The Winter Soldier.mkv          1 280  x 534  
*.avi                                               x  
*.m4v                                               x
```

There are only .mp4 and .mkv files in this folder, so it printed "*.avi" and "*.m4v." How can I suppress the printing of the extensions that it didn't find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting the shell's `nullglob` option: `shopt -s nullglob`. From `man bash`:

> If  no  matching filenames are found, and the
>          shell option `nullglob` is not enabled, the word is left  unchanged.   If
>          the  `nullglob`  option  is  set,  and  no matches are found, the word is
>          removed.